# Setting correct column range in VBA for excel

Tags: excel, vba

so I have two ranges set in two codes. My problem is, the range is specific. No matter how much I changed it, I end up getting an error. My goal is to set the range from C1 all the way until the data stops (same for column J). The range varies depending which spreadsheet I have open so I would like it to detect the end of the data and stop there. Each cell will ALWAYS have data so you don't have to worry about empty cells in between.

Here is my code:

```
    Sub Condition()
        Set Rng = Range("C1:C1822")
        For Each cell In Rng

        If cell.Value <> "SB" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Introduced by Assemblymember"
        Else
        cell.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Introduced by Senator"

        End If
        Next
    End Sub
'CORRECT LOWER CASE THEN UPPER CASE FIRST LETTER AND OFFSET TO NEW COLUMN

Sub Change()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("J1:J1822")
    For Each c In Rng
        c.Offset(, 2).Value = LCase(c.Value)
    Next c

For Each cell In Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If (cell.Value <> "") Then
         cell.Value = UCase(Left(cell.Value, 1)) & Right(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - 1)

    End If
Next
End Sub
```

My problem relies in the beginning at:

```
Sub Condition()
        Set Rng = Range("C1:C1822")
        For Each cell In Rng
```

and later shows up again at:

```
Sub Change()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("J1:J1822")
    For Each c In Rng
        c.Offset(, 2).Value = LCase(c.Value)
    Next c

For Each cell In Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If (cell.Value <> "") Then
         cell.Value = UCase(Left(cell.Value, 1)) & Right(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - 1)

    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will adjust to the number of populated rows:

```
Dim sht as WorkSheet, Rng As Range

Set sht = ActiveSheet   

Set Rng = sht.Range(sht.Range("C1"), sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count,"C").End(xlUp))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your suggestion worked perfectly.